# WPF with WindowsFormsHost Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, drag-and-drop, windowsformshost

I'm struggling to get Drag and Drop work on `WindowsFormsHost` when I drag on a file from the desktop, the `Drop` event just doesn't fire.

I created a sample project to demonstrate:

You need to reference `WindowsFormsIntegration` and `System.Windows.Forms`

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        AllowDrop="true"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <WindowsFormsHost 
                Background="red" 
                Height="200"
                AllowDrop="true"
                Drop="WindowsFormsHost_Drop">
                <wf:MaskedTextBox Height="200"  x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000"/>
            </WindowsFormsHost>
            <ListBox Name="LogList" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LogList.Items.Add("initialized");
        }


        private void WindowsFormsHost_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            LogList.Items.Add("fileDropped");
            LogList.Items.Add($"FileSource: {e.Source}");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: `<wf:MaskedTextBox x:Name="mtbDate" Mask="00/00/0000" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="MtbDate_DragEnter" DragDrop="MtbDate_DragDrop"/>`. Add the event handlers to the WinForms Control. In `MtbDate_DragEnter`: `e.Effect = System.Windows.Forms.DragDropEffects.Copy;` -- Your `DragEventArgs` in `WindowsFormsHost_Drop` should give you a *ambiguous reference* exception, since you need to have System.Windows.Forms referenced there.

Comment: Btw, you can remove `AllowDrop="true"` from `WindowsFormsHost`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I tested this qiute a bit and I can only guess that this is due to incompability of WinForms and WPF. From what I researched, events not always flow thorugh controls when those technologies are invloved.

But I can suggest something to work around this limitation - keep events in WPF controls, so define invisible, underlying control (that will occupy exactly the same area as `WindowsFormsHost`) to capture events:

```
<Grid>
    <Border
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        AllowDrop="True"
        Background="Transparent"
        Drop="WindowsFormsHost_Drop" />
    <WindowsFormsHost
        Name="wfh"
        Height="200"
        Background="red">
        <wf:MaskedTextBox
            x:Name="mtbDate"
            Height="200"
            Mask="00/00/0000" />
    </WindowsFormsHost>
</Grid>
```

I think that you might try even to set `IsHitTestVisible` of `WindowsFormsHost` to `false`, so all UI events should fall through - but it is up to you to test and decide if you want it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, it does work in my sample app, but I have failed to translate it to my actual project, hence why I didn't mark it as the answer yet. Still fishing for some other answers